# What is the beginning and the end of this disassembled array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

In a disassembled dll (by IDA), I reached an array, which is commented as an array of `int` (but it may be of `byte`):

```
.rdata:000000018003CC00 ; int boxA[264]
.rdata:000000018003CC00 boxA            dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: BlockPrepXOR+5FC↑r
.rdata:000000018003CC04                 db  0Eh
.rdata:000000018003CC05                 db  0Bh
.rdata:000000018003CC06                 db  0Dh
.rdata:000000018003CC07                 db    9
.rdata:000000018003CC08                 db  1Ch
.rdata:000000018003CC09                 db  16h
.rdata:000000018003CC0A                 db  1Ah
.rdata:000000018003CC0B                 db  12h
.rdata:000000018003CC0C                 db  12h
.rdata:000000018003CC0D                 db  1Dh
.rdata:000000018003CC0E                 db  17h
.rdata:000000018003CC0F                 db  1Bh
```

Can I interpret the data as

1. `{000000h, E0B0D09h, 1C161A12h, ..}` or
2. `{0, 90D0B0Eh, 121A161Ch, ...}` or
3. `{00h,00h,00h,00h, 0Eh, 0Bh, ..}` ?

From the comment (from IDA), can you confirm that the array ends at `CC00h + 253*4 = D01Fh` ? I have another array starting at `D020h`:

```
.rdata:000000018003D01D                 db 0F9h ; ù
.rdata:000000018003D01E                 db 0A2h ; ¢
.rdata:000000018003D01F                 db  3Fh ; ?
.rdata:000000018003D020 array4_1248     db    1                 ; DATA XREF: BlockPrepXOR+39A↑o
.rdata:000000018003D021                 db    2
.rdata:000000018003D022                 db    4
.rdata:000000018003D023                 db    8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the AES decryption's *T8* matrix as described in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-05445-7_10.pdf).
You can easily identify it by looking for the DWORDs values on Google (e.g. [this is one of the results](https://github.com/EmpireProject/EmPyre/blob/master/data/agent/stager.py#L264)).

So that's just data for an **AES decryption function**.

Note also that the interpretation of a sequence of bytes as a sequence of multi-byte data (WORDs, DWORDs, QWORDs, and so on) depends on the architecture.
For x86, only the little-endian interpretation is correct (this is your case 2) but data may undergo arbitrary manipulations (e.g. it can be `bswap`ped) so, when looking on Google, always use both the little and the big-endian versions of the data.

It's also worth noting that IDA can interpret the bytes as DWORDs (type `d` twice or use the context menù), showing the correct value based on the architecture of disassembled binary.

Comment: Thanks for the T8 tip. But wich interpretation is correct ? 1/2/3 ? Furthermore, it is not clear which of 1/2 is little endian (I'm working on x86).

Comment: @Soleil: Your question's number 2 is little-endian.

Comment: @Soleil Oops, sorry I thought you wanted to know what that vector was. As ecm courteously pointed out, it's your case 2.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks. I could change the data into an array, but it's an array of bytes; I could not find away to make it an array of uint (4 bytes). When I use `d` to change the type, it works only on the first element as data, not on the array.

Comment: @Soleil Define the first DWORD then use the array command (`*`). There are plenty of IDA tutorials (including the official doc) to make it do what you want. If you give up every time you face a (small) problem, reverse engineering will eat you alive :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks ;) I never give up !